# Best alternative to eval() to convert string back to function?

Tags: jquery

Since I've been hearing from a lot of people that using eval() and new Function() is deemed as an unsafe function due to it's ultra-dynamic nature.
I just need to convert a string which was originally a function, back to function so to use this function in other clusters as well.
This is a simple test program I've developed for your convenience, it's for eval() function and it's is working fine. Is there any alternative way other than eval() or even new Function()??

```
$(document).ready(function(){

savecallback = function() {
alert("testing savecallback");
}

var stringname = "function() {alert("testing savecallback");}";

jQuery(".divclass").click(function() {
 eval(stringname);
});

});
```

EDIT:

I'm sorry guys, actually the string is storing the entire function implementation instead of function name for what I've inspected in my project file. Edited the code above (in var stringname).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why eval() and new Funciton() are not safe is exactly since they can produce and/or run executable code. You do need to produce executable code, so any way you will find is unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing there's probably a better all-around solution for what you're trying to do -- more information about what problem you're trying to solve might be helpful :)

from what you've posted, i'd consider using an object property for your function, and then saving the object property name instead of the full function execution string:

```
// object to store callbacks on
var callbacks = {};

// define your callback
callbacks['savecallback'] = function() {
  alert('testing savecallback');
}

// save your callback name
var stringname = 'savecallback';

jQuery(".divclass").click(function() {
  // call your callback by name
  callbacks[stringname]();
});
```

if there's some or all of this code you can't control (the callback definition, or the saved string) then let us know -- there are ways around that too.  if the callback is defined in window scope you can `window[stringname]();` and if you can't change the callback string, you can `stringname = stringname.replace('()','');`.  in any case, if you can use the string to identify the function to run instead of actually `eval`, that would be best.

**EDIT:** if the entire function implementation is the string, you're pretty much stuck with `eval`.  you might be able to try inserting the string into the dom within a script tag, but this would be just as dangerous as the eval, if it even works (untested).  pretty much any time you have code you want executed that's in string format, you're running the risk of executing any old content in that string.  as long as you're aware of the risks, eval isn't the end of the world -- try to keep it as closed off as possible, e.g.:

```
function getEvalClosure(evalCode) {
  return function() { return eval(evalCode); }
}

jQuery(".divclass").click(function() {
  var f = (getEvalClosure(stringname))();
  // i noticed your code is itself a function, 
  // so you'd have to run it after eval-ing it into existence
  f();
});
```

it won't ever be 'safe', but remember that end users can monkey with any part of your javascript anyway, so i wouldn't recommend doing anything too sensitive purely in client javascript in the first place.  in this case the 'getEvalClosure' function creates a new scope for the eval to work in, keeping it one step further from the rest of your code.  i used to use eval pretty extensively in transforming stringified JSON from AJAX requests back before every library did it automatically -- in fact i bet there's still an eval() or two to be found even in those implementations.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed list of functions that you want to call (i.e. you know all the possible functions in advance), you could create a map of string->function and lookup the function based on a string key.

This way, you can call the functions safely without worrying about running a dangerous `eval()` on the user's input.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    savecallback = function() {
        alert("testing savecallback");
    }

    anothercallback = function() {
        alert("testing anothercallback");
    }

    var availableFunctions = {
        "savecallback()": savecallback,
        "anothercallback()": anothercallback
    };

    var stringname = "savecallback()";

    jQuery(".divclass").click(function() {
        if (stringname in availableFunctions) {
            availableFunctions[stringname].call();
        }
    });

});
```